# Can a Thief Steal a Really Impressive Title?

Tags: munchkin

I thought that this one was pretty simple, but the argument got heated after *multiple* instances of challenging the rule that a thief can only steal something tangible, like weapons/potions/etc. The notion that a thief could steal your title is akin to (according to my argument) stealing someone's job.

What's the verdict?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thieves can only steal Items. An Item either has a gold piece value or "No value" printed in the corner. Really Impressive Title has neither of these, so it is not an Item, so it can't be stolen.

Note that in earlier editions of Munchkin, this card was actually misprinted, and confusingly did in fact say "No Value". Per the official Errata, this is [corrected in the 19th printing](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/errata/munchkin/munchkin.html):

> **Corrected Errata**
>
> *Corrected in the 19th Printing*
>
> Really Impressive Title is not an item, so it should not say "No Value"

Comment: And there you have the basis of my argument. The big rock, aside from being next to useless, does serve an important purpose in distinguishing items of tangible and intrinsic value.